# Как вывести сразу несколько ответов?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть код на js -

```
function getCheckedCheckBoxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  var checkboxesChecked = []; // можно в массиве их хранить, если нужно использовать 
  for (var index = 0; index < checkboxes.length; index++) {
     if (checkboxes[index].checked) {
        checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[index].value); // положим в массив выбранный
        $('.otvet1').html(checkboxes[index].value); // делайте что нужно - это для наглядности
     }
  }
  return checkboxesChecked; // для использования в нужном месте
}
```

И

```
<label class="radiotext"><input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="HTML">HTML</label> <label class="radiotext"><input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="CSS">CSS</label> <label class="radiotext"><input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" value="SASS">SASS</label> <label class="radiotext"><input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" value="JS">JS</label> <label class="radiotext"><input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox5" id="checkbox5" value="BOOTSTRAP">BOOTSTRAP</label> <button onclick="getCheckedCheckBoxes()"> Кто выбран? </button>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Он выводит только один текст.
Как сделать чтобы выводил несколько?

Comment: Во первых покажите, как вы полученный результат отрисовываете(в вопросе не нашел), где появляется только одно значение и во вторых у вас ошибка в ваших input -> тег value присутствует 2 раза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью `querySelectorAll` можно сразу достать выбранные чекбоксы

```js
function getCheckedCheckBoxes() {
  let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  let checkboxesArray = [];
  output.textContent = '';

  for (let i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxesArray.push(checkboxes[i].value);
    output.innerHTML += checkboxes[i].value + '<br>';
  }
  return checkboxesArray;
}
```

```html
<label class="radiotext">
    <input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="HTML">HTML
</label>
<label class="radiotext">
    <input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="CSS">CSS
</label>
<label class="radiotext">
    <input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="SASS">SASS
</label>
<label class="radiotext">
    <input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" value="JS">JS
</label>
<label class="radiotext">
    <input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox5" value="BOOTSTRAP">BOOTSTRAP
</label>

<button onclick="getCheckedCheckBoxes()"> Кто выбран?</button>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем примере конструкция `$('.otvet1').html(checkboxes[index].value);` при каждом выполнении перезаписывает содержимое элемента вывода *otvet1*, поэтому и выводится только значение самого последнего отмеченного чекбокса.

Так как в примере есть массив со значениями всех выбранных чекбоксов `checkboxesChecked`, то можно просто вывести значения, добавленные в него в результате выполнения цикла.

```js
function getCheckedCheckBoxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  var checkboxesChecked = []; 
  for (var index = 0; index < checkboxes.length; index++) {
     if (checkboxes[index].checked) {
        checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[index].value);
     }
  }
  $('.otvet').html(checkboxesChecked.map((item) => `<p>${item}</p>`));
  
  return checkboxesChecked;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radiotext"><input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="HTML">HTML</label>
<label class="radiotext"><input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="CSS">CSS</label>
<label class="radiotext"><input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" value="SASS">SASS</label>
<label class="radiotext"><input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" value="JS">JS</label>
<label class="radiotext"><input name="spisok" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox5" id="checkbox5" value="BOOTSTRAP">BOOTSTRAP</label>
<button onclick="getCheckedCheckBoxes()"> Кто выбран? </button>
<div class="otvet"></div>
```